# Should I include teaching experience in my CV for a postdoc position?

Tags: postdocs, teaching, cv

I'm finishing a PhD in theoretical Physics and I'm going to apply to a postdoc position in Europe. In that case, should I include teaching experience in my CV? Indeed, during my masters and my PhD I have helped in teaching quite a few undergraduate courses, mostly in mathematical methods for Physicists. The way it works here is that there is a professor who teaches two classes a week and a grad student who teaches one. I think I have something around six semesters total doing this.

Now I'm unsure whether I should include it or not. On the one hand it seems not much relevant, as a postdoc position is for research work. On the other hand it seems like it adds some value, but I'm not sure.

So, should I include teaching experience in a CV for a postdoc position or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you should.  It illustrates that you have experience at preparing material for presentation, at communicating science, and that you can interact with others.  All of these are very valuable research skills.